# Excel/VBA issues with Application Username error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to vlookup a name in a sheet via VBA using below script and get

> Run time error 1004, 
>   Application defined or object defined error.

```
 Sub test()
Dim email As Variant
Dim name As String
name = Application.UserName
email = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheet1.Range("K:N"), 4, False)
MsgBox email
End Sub
```

However when I hardcode a name like below, it works fine, what am I doing wrong?

```
name = "Mike Thomson"
```

Comment: I suggest you to use a different name for variable `Name` because it's a command in VBA. Use something like `MyName`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in a new Excel workbook:

```
Sub TestMe()

    WriteData        
    Dim email As String
    Dim name As String: name = "Mike"  'Application.UserName
    email = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Worksheets(1).Range("K:N"), 4, False)
    MsgBox email

End Sub

Sub WriteData()

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Range("K1") = "Mike"
        .Range("K2") = "Mike2"
        .Range("N1") = "Mike@add.ress"
        .Range("N2") = "Mike2@add.ress"
    End With

End Sub
```

In general, it looks for value "Mike" in column "K" and returns the vlaue in column "N" of the corresponding row.

---

If there is a possible error, thus the `VlookUp()` does not find a good value then the following two options are possible:

- `Dim email As Variant` 
  It will return the number of the error in the `MsgBox()`, if an error exists. The reason is that `Variant` could take the error value in itself, and a String cannot.
- Use `IfError` and catch the error correspondingly. In the example below, it returns "No " and then the `name` variable:

---

```
Sub TestMe()

    WriteData

    Dim email As String
    Dim name As String: name = "Mike"  'Application.UserName
    With Application
        email = .WorksheetFunction.IfError(.VLookup(name, _
            Worksheets(1).Range("K:N"), 4, False), "No " & name)
    End With
    MsgBox email

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub test()

    Dim email As String
    Dim strname As String

    strname = Application.UserName
    email = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strname, Sheet1.Range("K:N"), 4, False)
    If email = "" Then
        MsgBox "No email found for " & strname & "."
    Else
        MsgBox "The email address assign to " & strname & " is " & email & "."
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, found the issue, the lookup table didn't had the same spelling as application.username. Hence it will throw that error.

Thank you guys for your assistance.